# Could not load texture: Guide.png

Tags: python, image, panda3d

[What I want is to load a picture in the Panda3D, but it can't run for the reason of could not load the texture. I really don't know why for the code could run well in the other environment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiHDC.png)

[This is the error information.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TUQ8.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)